# get next sibling element

Tags: javascript, jquery

can someone show me how to get only the next element

like when the first button is clicked, I only want the first message show

```
<div>
    <span class="button">Button</span>
    <span class="message" style="display:none;">first button clicked</span>


    <span class="button">Button</span>
    <span class="message" style="display:none;">second button clicked</span>


    <span class="button">Button</span>
    <span class="message" style="display:none;">third button clicked</span>

</div>
```

here is the jquery I have so far

```
<script>
$(this).next().fadeIn();
setTimeout(function(){$(this).next().fadeOut();}, 3000);
</script>
```

Comment: You forgot to bind the click handler.

Comment: You code works fine, provided its in a click handler: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5gfosceL/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    $(this).next().fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/wprxpeud/15/)**

Answer (score 0):

for your example, `next()` will suffice. it grabs a reference to whatever DOM element comes next

so you would setup a click handler like so

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var message = $(this).next();
    //do whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a click event like this instead:

```
$( ".button" ).click(function() {
  $(this).next().fadeIn();
  setTimeout(function(){$(this).next().fadeOut();}, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your script like bellow

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    el.next().fadeIn();
    setTimeout(function(){
        el.next().fadeOut();
    }, 3000);
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/94/)